# What does Flink SQL Lateral Table grammar mean

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/functions/udfs/#table-functions

The following text is from the above link, I am wondering why Flink is using `joinLateral` for Table API and `LATERAL TABLE` for sql to describe that it is joining with a table function. Is it SQL standard to use `LATERAL` as the key word to express joining with table function or
It is Flink that chooses `LATERAL` to express joining with table function. I would like to know why `LATERAL` is used here.

> In the Table API, a table function is used with .joinLateral(...) or .leftOuterJoinLateral(...). The joinLateral operator (cross) joins each row from the outer table (table on the left of the operator) with all rows produced by the table-valued function (which is on the right side of the operator). The leftOuterJoinLateral operator joins each row from the outer table (table on the left of the operator) with all rows produced by the table-valued function (which is on the right side of the operator) and preserves outer rows for which the table function returns an empty table.

> In SQL, use LATERAL TABLE() with JOIN or LEFT JOIN with an ON TRUE join condition.